# using variable inside mysql update query in php

Tags: php, mysql, variables

```
<?php
    require 'functions/connection.php';
    $conn = Connect();
    $e_id = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['e_id']);
    $first_name = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);
    $e_salary = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['e_salary']);
    $e_startdate = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['e_startdate']);
    $e_department = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['e_department']);          
    $sql = "UPDATE employee SET firstname='$first_name' WHERE id=$e_id";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I'm trying to use the first_name variable inside the update query.

I tried echo the variable and its working...
this is my connection code that im using.

```
<?php


function Connect()
{
 $dbhost = "localhost";
 $dbuser = "root";
 $dbpass = "";
 $dbname = "company";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die($conn->connect_error);

 return $conn;
}

?>
```

if i i replace the variable with anything between "" the database is getting updated

Comment: are you getting any error? Also you are mixing `object-oriented` and `procedural` way. show your `connection.php` file

Comment: try single quotes around the `$e_id` variable

Comment: Best practice is to use prepared statements.   PDO is good for this, but if you are set on using mysqli, see:  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @B.Desai im getting the following error: Error updating record: Unknown column 'rida' in 'field list'

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest making it more secure and using prepared statements.  This is an example using mysqli, but I prefer PDO:

```
  <?php
        require 'functions/connection.php';
        $conn = Connect();

        // Prepare the query
        $myQuery = $conn->prepare("UPDATE employee SET firstname=? WHERE id=?");

        $e_id = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['e_id']);
        $first_name = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
        $last_name = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);
        $e_salary = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['e_salary']);
        $e_startdate = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['e_startdate']);
        $e_department = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['e_department']);          

        // Bind your variables to the placemarkers (string, integer)
        $myQuery->bind_param('si', $first_name, $e_id);

        if ($myQuery->execute() == false) {
        echo 'Error updating record: ' . $mysqli->error;
        }
        else {  
        echo 'Record updated successfully';
        }
        $myQuery->close();

    ?>
```

Note:  The 'cleansing' you're doing in the middle I have left, but it's not really necessary with prepared statements.

Comment: Actually, you want to remove the 'cleansing', if you want to match existing records for people such as `O'hara` and the like...

Comment: True, in this instance it looks like an integer ID lookup though.  I wanted to leave it there for a talking point, as opposed to doing it for the OP and the issue going under the radar, but you're absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

`functions/connection.php` (Now an object):

```
<?php
class Connect
{
 private $dbhost = "localhost";
 private $dbuser = "root";
 private $dbpass = "";
 private $dbname = "company";

 public $conn;

 public function __construct()
 {
    if($this->conn = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname))
    {
      //connection established
      //do whatever you want here
    }
    else
    {
      //Error occurred
      die($this->conn->error);
    }
 }

 //other functions here

}

?>
```

Change mysqli_query to: `$conn->conn->query($sql);`

Prepared statement:
`Avoid SQLI injection`

```
if($stmt = $conn->conn->prepare("UPDATE employee SET firstname = ? WHERE id = ?"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $first_name, $e_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo $stmt->affected_rows;
}
```

Final code:

```
<?php
    require 'functions/connection.php';
    $conn = new Connect();
    $e_id = $conn->conn->real_escape_string($_POST['e_id']);
    $first_name = $conn->conn->real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = $conn->conn->real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);
    $e_salary = $conn->conn->real_escape_string($_POST['e_salary']);
    $e_startdate = $conn->conn->real_escape_string($_POST['e_startdate']);
    $e_department = $conn->conn->real_escape_string($_POST['e_department']);          

    if($stmt = $conn->conn->prepare("UPDATE employee SET firstname = ? WHERE id = ?"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('si', $first_name, $e_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo $stmt->affected_rows;
    }
    $conn->conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: This isn't recommended - you should be using prepared statements for this kind of thing

Comment: Updated answer @ChrisJ